# How to add Java JSSC library to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jssc

I have problem with using JSSC library in Eclipse, I tried to add the files from a zip archive to my project, but can't even include `jssc.SerialPortList`.

Files inside the zip are `jssc.jar`, `COPYING` and the folders `src` and `javadoc`.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract all file somewhere.
2. In Eclipse: Project Properties -> Java Build path -> Libraries
3. Press Add external jars and choose jssc.jar
4. Enjoy